# Constantly running java application on server

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am looking to run a java application constantly on a server. I have experience with sevlets, however they do not run constantly. Through research I have found the common solution to this problem is to use a third party timing service; I am hesitant to use one of these as I coded my own complicated timing mechanism.

This application needs to be running 24/7; I am confused as to why people don't run into this problem more often - am I doing something stupid?

Comment: What prevents you from just executing your application and leaving it running there?

Comment: If the program needs to run constantly, let it run constantly.  I'm not sure I understand the problem.  You say you have experience with servlets, the thing that makes sure those things go when they need to is running constantly.

Comment: @jkbbot - I can think of two reasons: redeploying a WAR / class reloading, running out of PermGen space.

Comment: What do you mean that your servlets "do not run constantly"? Can you be a little more specific as to what you want to accomplish?

Comment: @dcsohl I do not want to have to open a connection for my application to run

Comment: a servlet isn't **doing** anything just sitting there, **until** it handles a request.  Is you program pegging the CPU or something?  A servlet by itself doesn't use many CPU resources.

Comment: @Thufir Right, so I want my application to be running, doing things, without having to wait for a connection.

Comment: I don't get it, you need to put some context.  You need some sort of loop, `int x=0;while(true){System.out.println(x);x++;}` will run forever...but it's rather pointless.  What does your program **do**?

Comment: The advantage of a servlet is that it's **interactive**.  The **user**, or something, starts a chain reaction which runs the program.  The servlet just sits there and waits.  You need a mechanism to start, and stop, whatever it is you're doing.  You can also use `Thread` and `sleep` if you like.

Comment: @Thufir I don't want a servlet though, that is my problem. I want to be able to run an application 24/7, it does not take any connections. I think I may be able to use a virtual machine? I don't know.

Comment: a server is just a computer.  you can just run your program on their and calculate `x++` to infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seems to be "how do I get my program to run 24/7?" and the answer is:

1.)  leave your computer on 24/7 and let the program run.

2.)  put your program onto something like:  www.digitalocean.com for $5 per month and...let the program run.  Just like your computer.

It's already been described by William Falcon, there are many cloud hosts.

To expand on that, you just copy `MyProgramThatRunsForever.jar` over to the remote server, and run it in the background, something like that.  It will run and run and run, doing whatever it is that it does...

If you ask maybe a different question, you will get better answers.  I, for one, have no idea why you want to do this and think this is a good idea.

See:

> The X-Y Problem, as it is sometimes called, is a mental block which
>   leads to enormous amounts of wasted time and energy, both on the part
>   of people asking for help, and on the part of those providing help. It
>   often goes something like this:
>
> ```
> User wants to do X.
> User doesn't know how to do X, but thinks they can fumble their way to a solution if they can just manage to do Y.
> User doesn't know how to do Y either.
> User asks for help with Y.
> Others try to help user with Y, but are confused because Y seems like a strange problem to want to solve.
> After much interaction and wasted time, it finally becomes clear that the user really wants help with X, and that Y wasn't even a suitable solution for X.
> ```

XyProblem

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: also, in your question you assert that servlets do **not** run constantly.  That's absolutely **wrong**.  They **do** run all the time, they are there **waiting** to be invoked.  It's quite easy to just give a servlet a task and it will crank away without ever being invoked.  Just put the code in the init method of the servlet...

Answer (score 1):

Use a cloud host. For example you can use amazon aws to create a free ec2 instance. These are called micro instances. Then you can install java on the machine and run whatever you want.

1. Create an Amazon aws account
2. Create a new EC2 instance
3. Choose operating system (use ubuntu/linux)
4. Start up instance
5. ssh into EC2 instance
6. Install java
7. Do whatever you want. You are basically in a brand new linux computer

Answer (score 1):

I am highly recommend OpenShift. It's offer free cloud with support for Java and J2EE app containers and servers (tomcat, JBoss, Jetty ... ).
You can deploy your app there and use a lot of prepared modules such as cron, maven, ... You can setup Jenkins...

I am using it for nearly 2 years for development purposes.

Comment: So if I put my application on this cloud service the code will run continuously without having to open a connection?

Comment: https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/application/52bede84e0b8cdfab80002fd-dur/cartridge_type/cron-1.4  for the original poster.  This is awesome, however, never knew about openshift.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would probably be to refactor parts of your application that need to be run constantly to a new application, run it from command line (or cron) and use some sort of [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter_Process_Communication) to communicate with Servlet.

That being said, you probably are doing "something stupid". Servlets are built upon connections, actually the whole Internet is built upon the notion of connection. I can't possibly imagine any sort of web-related task that you'd need to run regardless of having connections or not. If it's some kind of background service, they are ususally related to administrative tasks and implemented as a shell scripts. If you must do it in Java, refer to above paragraph, but do not try to develop it as Servlet and deploy in servlet container. That's definitely wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

From your other question, you seem to already know how to do this:

> Deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk
>
> The Elastic Beanstalk server is an Eclipse WTP server with added
>   functionality for restarting, publishing, and terminating your Java
>   web application. The Elastic Beanstalk server in Eclipse represents an
>   AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment. An environment is a running
>   instance of an application on the AWS platform. Define Your Server
>
> Before deploying your application, you must define your server and
>   configure your application.
>
> To define your Java web application server
>
> ```
> In Eclipse, right-click your Java web project in the Project Explorer view. Select Amazon Web Services, and click Deploy to AWS
> ```
>
> Elastic Beanstalk.
>
> ```
> In the Run On Server wizard, select Manually define a new server.
> ```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.sdlc.html#create_deploy_Java.sdlc.create.deploy

Looking at this sample:

```
   @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
        getServletContext().log("init() called");
        count = 0;
    }
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet#Example

just put your code into the init method and will run and run and run.  Something like:

```
MyInfiniteLoopProject loop = new MyInfiniteLoopProject();
loop.countToInfinity();
```

and then, in your `MyInfiniteLoopProject` class, add this method:

```
public void countToInfinity(){
   int x=0;
   while(true){
        x++;
        System.out.println(x);
   }
}
```

and check your logs...

(well, depending on where System.out goes to, maybe use a logger)

Comment: Is this the best way to do this though? Are there any other options, this seems a bit hack.

Comment: it's very silly, don't do it.  I made the answer to illustrate that you are suffering from:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/177328  You need to ask a **new** question with some code, or at a minimum, outline **what** your code does.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use Openshift cloud host. 

1. Create an Openshift account. https://openshift.redhat.com
2. Enable applications you need in your project. (JBOSS , Tomcat , MySQL etc)
3. Install Client tools to enable remote access to the cloud server. Follow steps in below wiki.
https://www.openshift.com/developers/rhc-client-tools-install

4. Follow this wiki to create public and private keys. https://www.openshift.com/developers/remote-access
5. Connect to your server and deploy the build.
```