# Continously running java file for ex Server.java

Tags: java, networking

I am new to networking in java. I have a simple server.java and a client.java file. I complied both and server.class files responds to client.class file when I run it via command prompt. It works fine in local system i.e in my system when I run both the client as well as server. But I want to host the server.java on some free hosting cloud servers where my file i.e server.java would run continuously. Now by doing that I can create multiple clients to connect to that server.java file from anywhere via internet. It would be not local. I have seen other questions regarding this topic but it didn't help. I just want to know how should I get started to achieve the concept that I have stated above.

Similiar problem: [network in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20804043/constantly-running-java-application-on-server)

Comment: you mean that is "available" continuously? that's completely different compared to "runs continuously"

Comment: create a webservice and run it on a webserver. it's the server (not your code) that must keep running.

Comment: i just want other clients to connect to it not on my system. i guess i  mean to run continuously on some free servers for demo purposes only

Comment: your code doesn't "run", it's the webserver on which it is deployed that must continue running.

Comment: well how? i am completely lost here

Comment: here's a good place to start. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijvh.html

Comment: beyond my current learning ability

Comment: not really. it'll just take a bit more time.
start with the basics and work your way up, don't try to get too much too fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, a web service would do (like posted on the comments above)

If you really need to go for sockets you will then need a server-socket within a wile loop to wait for incoming requests and open a new thread per client request. see a really basic example here: http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javanetexamples/

Comment: i can learn how to create connections b/w clients and servers but how do i get my app to be playable via internet like for tictactoe.I dont want to host the server on my laptop but on some free servers available and how should i do this?

Comment: OK, so this question is actually about hosting... sorry. There are two options: 1.) implement it as a Java JEE web application and run it on an application server like tomcat, glass fish or jboss. or 2.) just run the jar on the terminal (at server side) which is not recommended but a start anyway. in both options you will need wether a root/v-server where you have full access or a "webspace" that can run Java. A normal 08/15 webspace suitable for wordpress isn't enough here.

Comment: please also check here; there are several hosting providers for java mentioned: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606788/hosting-java-app-on-free-web-hosting-site

Comment: hmm that helps thanks.Well i will dig in then, i am kinda new to these stuff.

Comment: a question again.. do i have to create an executable jar file or just a jar file of the server.class file

Comment: yes, when you begin its a bit much (but in fact not that complicated at all). Once you did it on your own you will see. Try to find a first tutorial for a simple application server like tomcat or glass fish before switching to the big ones like JBoss.

Comment: to run your application on the shell / terminal you will need a executable jar; for a java web application / web service you will need a *.war file (or *.ear; but start with war as it is simpler for beginning)

Comment: well kinda confused....what is tomcat?lol does it help connect other clients via the internet? is it free? can you direct me in a proper direction, well i am a true rookie

Comment: Tomcat (and glassfish) are both Java application servers. This a "web server" to run java web-applications ("aka apache for java"). Tomcat webpage: http://tomcat.apache.org btw: both servers mentioned here are free ;)

Comment: this is a nice introduction: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaWebTerminology/article.html

Comment: but ultimately it will run on my laptop or system i.e the apache tomcat server, or do you mean that they will host your java ee web app for free? did you mean that?

Comment: nope ;) to be clear you need two things: 1. a machine / server where you can host your application (aka "webspace"); 2.) a runtime environment for your java application (JVM) which is your tomcat in the end. The tomcat will be installed on your machine/server; your application will be installed inside the tomcat (deployed).

Comment: oh so i should find free cloud hosting servers which supports tomcat